# Linked npm library not updating locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have the following library https://github.com/codyc4321/react-data-components-updated

I installed it in my react project locally like `npm i ~/react-data-components-updated`

Now running my node server I don't get any changes no matter what I do. I am seeing old print statements which I deleted, and my new ones are not coming:

```
  console.log('data in dataSort() in dataReducer.js:');
  console.log(state.data);
```

doesn't show up.

I have constantly reinstalled like `$ npm i ~/react-data-components-updated/` and it isn't helping. I was seeing weird errors affecting this location:

```
http://localhost:3001/__webpack_hmr
```

but right now I get a `200` for that address and it still isn't updating. How can I use this library locally and have my project update when it sees changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that your package got installed and is now in `your-project-folder/node_modules`, so in order for the modifications to replicate you have four options:

- Directly modify the scripts in `your-project-folder/node_modules/react-data-components-updated` **[not recommended]**
- Delete `your-project-folder/node_modules/react-data-components-updated` and run `npm i ~/react-data-components-updated`
- Run`npm uninstall react-data-components-updated && npm i ~/react-data-components-updated` so it reinstalls with the current files.
- Go to `~/react-data-components-updated/package.json` and upgrade the version manually ([or by CLI](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version)) and then running `npm update` in your project.

Depending on your needs and how you're handling changes in your local package, one may be better than the other.